# queing system for SAS jobs on server.

Tags: sas

I am not sure if this is the right place to post this question, so please direct me to the right forum if this is not the right place.

I am now using SAS on my local computer and Linux Server to submit the SAS programs for calculations and as the server doesnt have the queing system when all the ports are busy until unless someone logsoff the other cannot log in.

My questions is, is it possible to have a queing system to submit the SAS programs to the linux server that I use now? apart from the SAS Grid and SAS servers.

Comment: I would love to know this answer as well. Scheduling with SAS has always been a frustrating task for me. I've been in situations where the solution was to have a dedicated VM with a unique user just to run SAS jobs - and it could never be logged off.

I have heard flexible scheduling systems like ActiveBatch have had success with SAS, but that's a pricey solution.

Comment: @StuSztukowski I am looking for the same solution mate..! couldnt find any till date.